# Terminating an apply-based function early (similar to break?)

Tags: r

I am searching for a way to terminate an apply function early on some condition.  Using a for loop, something like:

```
FDP_HCFA = function(FaultMatrix, TestCosts, GenerateNeighbors, RandomSeed) {    
  set.seed(RandomSeed)

  ## number of tests, mind the summary column
  nT = ncol(FaultMatrix) - 1
  StartingSequence = sample(1:nT)
  BestAPFD = APFD_C(StartingSequence, FaultMatrix, TestCosts)
  BestPrioritization = StartingSequence
  MakingProgress = TRUE
  NumberOfIterations = 0
  while(MakingProgress) {
    BestPrioritizationBefore = BestPrioritization
    AllCurrentNeighbors = GenerateNeighbors(BestPrioritization)

    for(CurrentNeighbor in AllCurrentNeighbors) {
      CurrentAPFD = APFD_C(CurrentNeighbor, FaultMatrix, TestCosts)

      if(CurrentAPFD > BestAPFD) {
        BestAPFD = CurrentAPFD
        BestPrioritization = CurrentNeighbor            
        break
      }
    }

    if(length(union(list(BestPrioritizationBefore),
                    list(BestPrioritization))) == 1)
      MakingProgress = FALSE

    NumberOfIterations = NumberOfIterations + 1
  }
}
```

I would like to rewrite this function using some derivation of `apply`. In particular, terminating the evaluation of the first individual with increased fitness, thereby avoiding the cost of considering the rest of the population.

Comment: You might be able to use some combination of signalCondition/tryCatch/etc., but seems complicated.  I would second @JoshUlrich's question.

Comment: The code still does not work (I think its missing a `}` ) and there is no test driver so we still have nothing that we can run.  Also it would be nice if you could illustrate the basic idea with a shorter piece of code.

Comment: I was also looking for a way to break out early from an
apply-based loop, and found this thread. Even though some people claim that apply should be regarded as
"block code" rather than a "loop", I still think it would be
useful to have a possibility to break out of it. The reason is that the apply based functions seem to execute a lot faster, something like 10-100 times faster than a for-loop. Many times
I have run simple snippets in for loops that are not done after more than a few minutes, while the apply seems to get the same job done in mere seconds.

Comment: Hmm...well I believe I may have seen a post or two which would debate your claim, but speed wasn't really what I was after here (well, not that I would complain).  I'm working on a few search based algorithms in R, and the functions in the plyr package allow parallel/distributed function through foreach with the .parallel arg.  That allows for (easy) experimentation in efficiency with parallelism at various levels in the algorithms.

Answer (score 19):

I reckon that you don't really grasp the `apply` family and its purpose. Contrary to the general idea, they're **not** the equivalent of any `for`-loop. One can say that most `for`-loops are the equivalent of an `apply`, but that's another matter.

`Apply` does exactly as it says: it applies a function on a number of similar arguments sequentially, and returns the result. Hence, by definition you cannot break out of an apply. You're not operating in the global environment any more, so in principle you cannot keep global counters, check after each execution some condition and adapt the loop. You can access the global environment and even change variables using `assign` or `<<-`, but this is pretty dangerous.

To understand the difference, don't read `apply(1:3,afunc)` as `for(i in 1:3) afunc(i)`, but as

```
afunc(1)
afunc(2)
afunc(3)
```

in one (block) statement. That reflects better what you're doing exactly. An equivalent for `break` in an `apply` simply doesn't make sense, as it is more a block of code than a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from getting your sample code to work`*` I think this is a clear case where a loop is the right choice. Although R can apply a function to a whole vector of variables [EDIT: but you have to decide what they are before applying], in this case I'd use a `while` loop to avoid the cost of running unnecessary repetitions. Caveat: I know `for` loops have compared favorably with `apply` in timing tests, but I have not seen a similar test for `while`. Check out some of the options at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Control-structures.

```
while ( *statement1* ) *statement2*
```

---