# Equivalent "break" for the lapply function

Tags: r, lapply, break

I am trying to make a function that will terminate conditionally. Let this condition be "`if (i == 5)`"

```
le <- letters
for(i in seq_along(let)){
   ## some code
  print(le[i])
  if(i==5) break
}
```

with `for` everything goes well

```
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
[1] "d"
[1] "e"
```

but when I use `lapply` I get an error

```
fu <- function(i){
  ## some code
  print(le[i])
  if(i==5) break
} 
lapply(1:length(le) , fu)
```

res

```
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
[1] "d"
[1] "e"
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916435/terminating-an-apply-based-function-early-similar-to-break)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix it, and there aren't any simple workarounds.  `lapply()` doesn't support `break`.  If you want break, you need to use a different kind of loop.

Here's one workaround:

```r
le <- letters

fu <- local({
  broken <- FALSE
  function(i){
    if (broken) return()
    ## some code
    print(le[i])
    if(i==5) broken <<- TRUE
  }
})

res <- lapply(1:length(le) , fu)
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] "b"
#> [1] "c"
#> [1] "d"
#> [1] "e"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you look at `res`, you'll see that it contains 21 `NULL`s, because it is still called 26 times.  You can't stop that without very dangerous messing around in `lapply()` internal variables.